# How to Display SubCategory Products in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a relation between category, subcategory, and sub child category, and `product` is related to `sub child category`, but I want to display the list of `subcategory` products. Please let me know how I can do it.

here is my `models.py` file...

```
class Category(models.Model):
    cat_name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
    cat_slug=models.SlugField(max_length=225, unique=True)

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    subcat_name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
    subcat_slug=models.SlugField(max_length=225, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='subcategoryies', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)


class SubChildCategory(models.Model):
    subcategory=models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, related_name='SubChildRelated', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None, verbose_name='Sub Category')
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None)
    slug=models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=50)
```

here is my `product models.py` file...

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=225, unique=True)
    subcategory=models.ManyToManyField(SubChildCategory, related_name='pro_subchild', verbose_name='Select Category')
```

here is my `views.py` file, where I am trying to display the `SubCategory` product...

```
def home(request):
    subcat_product = Product.objects.prefetch_related('subcategory')
    return render(request, 'frontend/index.html',{'subcat_product':subcat_product}
```

but the above function is displaying all the products which are available in `SubChildCategory`, I want to display products according to the `SubCategory` on my homepage.

Please let me know what is the process to display these products.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work:

```
# You can also get your sub category by id
sub_child_categories = SubCategory.objects.get(
    slug=your_sub_category_slug
).SubChildRelated.all()

subcat_products = Product.object.none()

for sub_child_category in sub_child_categories:
    subcat_products |= sub_child_category.pro_subchild.all()
```

`subcat_products` is all the products that the a `SubCategory` has.

Comment: could you please write it inside my function

Comment: inside your `def home(self)`, and you need to pass the `slug` of `SubCategory` to your home page @sainitor